# WCF : pushing data between two independent applications

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF. I just finished my first WCF Service Project and I would like to know what is the most convenient way to achieve this :

I would like to have App A send Data to App B. Applications A & B are independent as of now.

I thought of something like the sketch below, where H is the service Host exposing Service S.

Service S would have contracts & methods to consume (get) data from A (invoked by A) and to push (set) data to B (invoked by B -well I guess..)

In your opinion, is this relevant ?

[image]

Comment: Oh god. Paint FTW. If `A` is sending to `B`, why is it not `A` that is pushing as well data from `H` to `B`?

Comment: @Otiel : I studied UML and bought expensive Visio License but I can't stop thinking that a good'ol sketch on a paperboard is killer efficient :-P  The whole point is that "A" doesn't see "B". But yes, I guess a "push toward B" action can also be triggered on the initiative of "A". However, I still wonder how should B get the Data. I want it to be passive and get data whenever it is available from S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your *"However, I still wonder how should B get the Data. I want it to be passive and get data whenever it is available from S"* comment: you should implement a service also on `B` that will enable `H` to send to `B` some data.

This is how I see your project, in a macroscopic way:

`H` and `B` are implementing a `[OperationContract]` called `ReceiveData(Data myData)`.

- When `A` wants to send data, he calls `ReceiveData()` on `H`.
- When `H` gets the data and detect it is for `B`, he calls `ReceiveData()` on `B`.

The whole point is that `B` **is, like** `H`**, hosting a service**.

Comment: This is precisely what I was wondering. This means a Second Service. A first, I was considering to embed both behaviours on one single Service...

Comment: After giving it a thought, I think your proposition is sensible for what I want to do... It performs efficient decoupling since B exposes its service interface to be fed from the "outside", hence being passive, rather that having to call S for update, or to be "seen" by S, which would break decoupling. Thank you, your help was precious to me. BTW, I love SOF Community so much, I work freelance alone in my office and the community is like a huge open space fulled of skilled colleagues ready to help. Much Love Dudes :-)

Comment: I could even get rid of H and host S directly on B and have it called by A that would simplify the architecture

Answer (score 2):

If you want to decouple two applications it is certainly an option to add a service 'in between'.

There are some design patterns that address this kind of problem. The following book/site has some really good information: [Enterprise Integration Patterns.](http://eaipatterns.com/index.html)

The application in the middle could be a Broker which has a well defined interface and connects all the applications that talk to it. It knows how to distribute events to the client applications without strict coupling between those clients.